# Can I add random nodes on edges manually in OSMNX?

Tags: networkx, geopandas, osmnx

I am new to OSMnx and to NetworkX packages in python.

Let's say I have the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import networkx as nx


place_name = 'Fefan'
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type='drive')
graph_proj = ox.project_graph(graph)
nodes_proj= ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph_proj, nodes=True, edges=False)
ox.plot_graph(graph_proj)
```

As you can see, I only obtain the two nodes for this place. I guess that's how it is in OSM. Is there any way I can manually add random nodes in this graph, especially on the edges of it?

For a broader picture. I need the nodes to calculate some distance matrices between some buildings, which are not shown here.

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the following way.

Import nodes and edges as geodataframes.

```
import numpy as np
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import networkx as nx


place_name = 'Fefan'
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type='drive')
nodes= ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=True, edges=False)
edges= ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, edges=True, nodes=False)
ox.plot_graph(graph)
```

Create a dictionary for the new nodes. I have just added one new node in this case.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import  Point

my_dict = {
  '001': {
    'y': 7.367210, 
    'x': 151.838487,
    'street_count': 1
  }
}
```

Create a new geodataframe for the new node.

```
tmp_list = []
for item_key, item_value in my_dict.items() :
  tmp_list.append({
    'geometry' : Point(item_value['x'], item_value['y']),
    'osmid': item_key,
    'y' : item_value['y'],
      'x' : item_value['x'],
    'street_count': item_value ['street_count']
   })
my_nodes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(tmp_list)
```

Append new geodataframe (`my_nodes`) to the old geodataframe (`nodes`) to modify the old geodataframe and plot.

```
nodes = nodes.append(my_nodes, ignore_index = True)
graph2 = ox.graph_from_gdfs(nodes, edges)
ox.plot_graph(graph2)
```

[image]