# Find points where a polygon and the road network intersect

Tags: networkx, polygon, shapely, osmnx

I want to find the intersecting points between a polygon and the road network and add them to the network as nodes.

```
import osmnx as ox
import folium
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
G = ox.graph_from_place('Lebanon, NH, USA', network_type='drive')
m1 = ox.plot_graph_folium(G, edge_color = "red")
polygon = Polygon([(-72.2460023,43.6225941), (-72.2547570,43.6063131),(-72.2329560,43.6007194),(-72.2272912,43.6136463),(-72.2460023,43.6225941)])
folium.GeoJson(data=polygon).add_to(m1)
```

The second part of what I seek to do can be accomplished in a pretty straightforward fashion - has previously been answered on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71437958/can-i-add-random-nodes-on-edges-manually-in-osmnx).

I'm presuming I would have to get both the polygon and the road network as linestrings (perhaps by rounding the points in the line string to a number of significant digits) to find the common latitude and longitude points.

Here is an image of the points (encircled in black) I'd like to add to the network, as a minimalistic example.

[image: Points where the polygon intersects the road network]

The folium map is reproducible from the code above.

An alternative method that could also be useful in my case, is if I am able to say that there are two unconnected road network segments (in orange) within the polygon (might be more "unconnected" segments in some other road networks).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#splitting) might help.

Comment: @Ouroborus - Yes. If the graph were in individual line strings instead of a Multi-di-Graph. I could potentially run a local search in the vicinity of the polygon and get the linestrings along the edges. However, it becomes tricky when there are many edges extending outside the polygon.

Comment: Geopandas might also be useful here.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev I've used GeoPandas quite extensively. Any specific functionality that you have in mind? I haven't succeeded thus far.

Comment: @hedgep: hmm, maybe I misunderstand the problem, but isn't this a variation on: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/345038/176433 (old link was a different way, but seems also possible https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230509/176433).

Comment: Yeah - geopandas.sjoin seems like it should do exactly what you’re looking for

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev The first link is actually super helpful. However, the clip function seems to now have been merged into geopandas. `ped = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes = False)` and `clipped_df = gpd.clip(ped, polygon)
` did it for me. However, it isn't straightforward to group the connected linestrings together.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado sjoin gives you only one part of the result I'm looking for, as mentioned in the first link Sultan posted.