# How can I add buildings as nodes in a graph in osmnx?

Tags: networkx, osmnx

I am not very familiar with osmnx. I am trying to create  graph that contains nodes
in the center of each building, as well as street nodes. The following code shows the buildings (not as nodes) and street nodes together:

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
from matplotlib import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from IPython.display import Image
import geopandas as gpd
from IPython.display import IFrame


place = "Piedmont, California, US"
G = ox.graph_from_place(place)

tags = {'building': True}
buildings = ox.geometries_from_place(place, tags)



# or plot street network and the entities' footprints together
fig, ax = ox.plot_footprints(buildings, alpha=0.4, show=False)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, ax=ax, node_size=10, edge_color="w", edge_linewidth=0.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do so by extracting the coordinates of the centroid of each building
and adding new nodes there:

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
from matplotlib import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point
from IPython.display import Image
import geopandas as gpd
from IPython.display import IFrame

# Specify the name that is used to seach for the data
place_name = "kirchberg, luxembourg, luxembourg"

# Fetch OSM street network from the location
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name)

nodes= ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, nodes=True, edges=False)
edges= ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph, edges=True, nodes=False)
#ox.plot_graph(graph)


for i in range(len(list(graph.nodes))):
    node_id = list(graph.nodes)[i]
#    print(f"lon: {graph.nodes[node_id]['x']}, lat: {graph.nodes[node_id]['y']}")



#print(graph.nodes)


buildings = ox.geometries_from_place(place_name, tags={
'building':True
}) # Retrieve buildings from the area:


#buildings = buildings.to_crs(4326)


centroids = buildings.centroid

#print(dir(centroids))

lons = list(centroids.x)

lats = list(centroids.y)


building_coords = [[lons[i],lats[i]] for i in range(len(lons))]

print(building_coords)

dictionary = dict()

for i in range(len(building_coords)):
     node_id = i+1
     dictionary[node_id] = {
    'x': lons[i],
    'y': lats[i]
     }

tmp_list = []
for item_key, item_value in dictionary.items() :
  tmp_list.append({
    'geometry' : Point(item_value['x'], item_value['y']),
    'osmid': item_key,
    'y' : item_value['y'],
      'x' : item_value['x'],
   })
my_nodes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(tmp_list)

# just plot the building nodes
nodes = my_nodes

# or plot building nodes and street nodes
#nodes = nodes.append(my_nodes, ignore_index = True)

graph2 = ox.graph_from_gdfs(nodes, edges)
#fig, ax = ox.plot_footprints(buildings, alpha=0.4, show=False)
#ox.plot_graph(graph2)
ox.plot_graph(graph2, node_size=10, edge_color="grey", node_color="green", edge_linewidth=0.7, bgcolor="white")
```

credit to Debjit Bhowmick for their code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71522176/19955073).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you linked "answer" does only lead to DIY Stackexchange, so other users can't follow your reasoning / explanation. In addition to that please try to explain how his solution has solved your problem at hand. Thank you!